# Number formatting Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I've noticed a strange bug while looking at my app on an Android device running 5.0.

On pre 5.0 devices my app will add commas into numbers where necessary. e.g "1,234" or "100,000"

On 5.0 devices the same code displays these numbers as "1234" or "100000". Has any one else noticed this?

I have included my code to format the numbers below - I'm not to sure what needs to change for lollipop devices to show the correct format.

```
public static String formatNumber(Integer number, String prefix) {
    if (prefix == null) {
        prefix = Constants.PREFIX_SYMBOL;
    }

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(prefix);
    NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(new Locale("en_UK"));
    stringBuilder.append("").append(numberFormatter.format(number));

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I think the solution to this is as follows

```
public static String formatNumber(Integer number, String prefix) {
    if (prefix == null) {
        prefix = Constants.PREFIX_SYMBOL;
    }

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(prefix);
    NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
    stringBuilder.append("").append(numberFormatter.format(number));

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Removing the Locale from the `NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();` call seems to do the trick. This is added in as some Locales will use non-ASCII decimal digits when formatting integers as specified [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#default_locale). I do not think that this is the case for the regions that my app is available in so it should do the trick.

EDIT:

```
NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(new Locale("en_UK"));
```

can be replaced with

```
NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(new Locale("en", "GB"));
```

This will prevent the default locales from using non-ASCII decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

To group digits you could use `DecimalFormat` instead of `NumberFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###");
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Yes this could be done, but using DecimalFormat you will have to cater for every possible size range being used. E.g ("#,###"), ("##,###") etc. NumberFormat will handle this itself.

Comment: That's not correct, the above specified format sets grouping with three digits. You could achieve the same effect using formatter.setGroupingSize(3).

Comment: Ahh I see, I'm assuming that the locale would still need to be specified along with the DecimalFormat in order to avoid non-ASCII decimal digits being used..?

Comment: No, it sets the grouping separator according to the user's locale. For example, in Italy it will be ".", while in the US ",". You are still able to set a custom separator through the method setDecimalFormatSymbols